# Firebase database rule - How to check if login already exists?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have read a lot of topics and search around but still have problems with the followings:

The structure of my database:

```
users
  -userKEY
    login: value
    password: value
```

Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "true",
        ".validate": "root.child('users').child('login').val() != newData.child('login').val()" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess `root.child('users').child('login')` is probably wrong, but still don't know how.

**I would like to iterate through all rows of `users` and check whether the login value of `newData.child('login').val()` has been used.**

Comment: Security Rules can check whether a specific path exists. Security Rules cannot check if a collection contains a child with a specific value. So that typically means you need to ensure you have a key with the login value. Note that it is unclear what `login: value` is, so I can't answer more concretely than this.

Comment: Situation is simple. I have created a registration component, so I need to check in database if given login already exists somewhere in user collection. I have no key.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing part of the path.. `$uid`

```
".validate": "root.child('users').child($uid).child('login').val() != newData.child('login').val()"
```

second attempt

```
".validate": "data.child('login').val() != newData.child('login').val()"
```

Comment: Still can add new users so something is wrong. I tried also something like: ```".validate": "!root.child('users/$uid/login/' + newData.child('login').val()).exists()"  ``` but there is still problem.